# Can't install Web3 (Module not found: ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js)

Tags: reactjs, npm, web3js

Getting this error when trying to npm install web3

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/username/Desktop/project/site/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' in '/Users/username/Desktop/project/site/my-app'

Comment: You should mention NodeJS/NPM version and OS details also. You may delete node_modules folder and clean cache forcefully and then try to install again.

Comment: I already tried deleting the folder and reinstalling, didn't work

Comment: remove node_modules folder, then npm cache clean, and try npm i again

Answer (score 0):

Okay...the issue fixed itself by closing VS Code and running npm run start again...